# How do I develop this action creator for stripe checkout payments?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, stripe-payments

I am attempting to integrate stripe payments into a react-redux project following this documentation:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=checkout

The documentation examples assumes React with no Redux. As a result, I am trying to develop an action creator for this portion here:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#add-an-event-handler-to-the-checkout-button

I have gotten this far:

```
export const handleClick = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.post("/api/create-checkout-session");

};
```

However, in the response back from the server, what type of action am I going to dispatch? Is it safe to assume that the backend server sends back the `current_user` model with the updated payment?

If so can I use the exact same `FETCH_USER` type that I created previously here:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.get("/api/current_user");
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

Also, am I passing this second action creator, the `handleClick` one, a `session.id`?

Also, saving the `session.id` on my reducer is doing nothing but giving me nasty errors.

```
import { FETCH_USER } from "../actions/types";
import { CHECKOUT_SESSION_CREATED } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  sessionId: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER:
      return action.payload || false;
    case CHECKOUT_SESSION_CREATED:
      state = {
        ...state,
        sessionId: action.payload,
      };
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, in the response back from the server, what type of action am I going to dispatch?

You would dispatch an action that would add the returned Session ID to your Redux state. You haven't shared your code for the `/api/create-checkout-session` endpoint, but assuming you're following the docs the response should contain an object of the form `{ id: 'cs_xyz' }`, where `cs_xyz` is the Checkout Session ID.

So, your action creator would look something like:

```
export const handleClick = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.post("/api/create-checkout-session");
  dispatch({ type: 'CHECKOUT_SESSION_CREATED', payload: res.data });
};
```

In response to that action, your reducer you would save the Session ID to your state. Then, your connected checkout component would check to see if a Session ID is defined; if so you would redirect to checkout. E.g.,

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: 'cs_xyz' }); // where `cs_xyz` is the ID you added to your store.
```